# Upload base64 encoded image with paperclip - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip

Using [cropit](https://github.com/scottcheng/cropit) I get the image bas64 encode on rails through params.

```
  image = params['image'].gsub('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '')
  decoded_file = Base64.decode64(image)
```

and then I save to amazon s3 with paperclip

```
   begin
    file = Tempfile.new(['image', '.jpg'])
    file.binmode
    file.write decoded_file
    unless params['image_id']
      media_img = Media::Image.new()
      media_img.image = file
      if media_img.save
        render json: {status: 'success'}
      else
        render json: {status: 'error'}
      end
    else
      img = Media::Image.find(params['image_id'])
      img.update_attribute(:image, file)
      img.update_attribute(:name, params['image_name'])
      render json: {status: 'success'}
    end
    file.close
  ensure
    file.unlink
  end
```

The main problem is that the code is working only for jpeg images because I use gsub only for `data:image/jpeg;base64,` and when creating the Tempfile I created jpg `Tempfile.new(['image', '.jpg'])` . So how can I handle with best practice jpg, jpeg and png?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution, using Paperclip.io_adapters.for(image) where image is base64 string.

```
def create_image image, image_name, cat
  signature = Paperclip.io_adapters.for(image)
  base_name = File.basename(image_name,File.extname(image_name))
  signature.original_filename = "#{base_name}.jpg"
  media_img = Media::Image.new()
  media_img.image = signature
  media_img.company_id = current_company_id
  media_img.type = cat
  media_img.save
end
```